# indirect speech

Tags: indirect-speech

How to write this sentence in indirect speech .
Eg 
He said" Some pokemons do not listen to their master".

I am confused between these two sentences.

He said that some pokemons did not listen to their master

Or

He said that some pokemons do not listen to their master.

Which one is correct

(as it is not general fact but a imaginary one i thought the first one is correct but the second one sounds more appropriate. so which one is correct)

Comment: I appreciate your link but I have slightly different problem. In that link it was about general facts. But I am asking about that is imaginary and which is perceived as fact in that show so it is about fantasies and I think that past tense should be used for grammar as it is imaginary one but the second one sounds more natural .so which one is more appropriate

Comment: I don't think the fact that it is imaginary makes any difference and would go with the second version.